# Android One Stuck in "Checking Connection" after Factory Reset

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, factory-reset, micromax

I did factory reset to my Micromax Android One (Canvas A1). Before resetting it was running Android Marshmallow 6.0.1 with July 2016 security updates. Now when I reboot the device, after language and SIM options, it asks me to select a WiFi. But it is stuck in "checking connection... this can take a while", even when the same WiFi is working with other devices. The Select WiFi and Checking connection pages can't be skipped as the Skip button is grayed out.

My device is not rooted and I don't want to root is as long as possible, so [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120531/nexus-4-stuck-at-checking-connection-after-factory-reset) doesn't help me.

I have tried various options suggested in forums and nothing is working for me. I have tried with and without SIM cards and Micro SD card as well. So far I have tried:

1. Running in recovery mode and  "wipe cache partition"
2. Resting the device again in Recovery mode
3. Used different WiFi, even tried using WiFi host-spot from other devices

How to fix this without rooting? Is there any way to skip this step?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to one of my friend some time ago. But his device and android version were different
Why you're trying to connect to any connection? Just remove the sim card and skip the **"Connect to a Network"** step. It will give you a prompt, select the `SKIP ANYWAY` option and you're good to go !. Later you can insert your sim card and connect to your favourite WiFi network and sign in to your accounts and whatever!. Just skip everything until you get to the homescreen.

This is the easiest method. Good Luck! Tell me what result you get.

Comment: As I have already mentioned in my question I can't bypass  "Connect to a Network" step. Skip option is grayed out and Skip Anyway is not available. Whether I try with or without SIM, the results are the same. Also to clarify, it is trying to connect to a WiFi network not a mobile network. This step can't be skipped st all.

Comment: Then you might wanna  try flashing  stock firmware again. 
Suggestion : Download the firmware of a lower android version that you're currently on or the version with which the phone was shipped ! good luck

Comment: Can you let me know how to do that. Any step by step procedure will be appreciated.